# `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Im using rails 4.1.1 and ruby 2.1.1 and am having an issue with devise, namely my routes..I have used this many times before

```
devise_for :users

get 'pages/index'

# Route to Devise Login Page
  devise_scope :user do
    root to: "devise/sessions#new"
  end

# Directing the user after login
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'pages#index'
  end
```

But i get the error

```
`add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'  (ArgumentError)
```

when trying to start the server.. I can see that root is being used twice, but like i said i have been able to do this in the past.. Is there a way around this

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

Found this helpful comment here on stackoverflow

> For Rails 4.0 you have to make sure you have unique names for the path
>   helpers, like root to: "dashboard#show", as: :authenticated_root.
>   Otherwise the authenticated root and the normal root route end up
>   having the same name for their path helpers, which Rails 4.0 no longer
>   allows

so I changed my authenticated root to helper like so

```
 # Directing the user after login
 authenticated :user do
   root :to => 'pages#index', as: :authenticated_root
 end
```

Comment: Thank you. Helped me while moving from Rails3 to Rails4!

Comment: So if we want to designate the `/` url wether the user's loggued in or not, we need to create an helper `def actual_root_path if user_signed_in? authenticated_root_path else root_path end end`? Sounds lame...