# Set root URL dynamically for A/B testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to do A/B testing for my `root_url`. I have it pointed to my `StaticController#index` method but from there I want to decide which page that the user should see depending on some parameters (like IP, cookie, randomness, etc). For example if the user should see `SearchController#index`, `StaticController#about`, `UserController#login`, and so on.

I could do a redirect but that means that the URL changes and the browser has to do a second request.

Is there a way to dynamically decide which controller and action that the `root_url` points to?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to render different pages in the controller action. However it would be the best if you just decided on which view to render and not completely different code (like in switch/case statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) in the routes definition :

```
class ABConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    request.remote_ip[-1].to_i.odd?   # not efficient !
  end
end

...

# Define the root_url with the constraint, and without the constraint.
constraints(ABConstraint.new) do
   root to: 'home#indexA', as: :root_a
end    
root to: 'home#indexB', as: :root_b
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. Got this: `ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' `

Comment: @ChristofferBrodd-Reijer I've updated my answer, based on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267292/add-route-invalid-route-name-already-in-use-root-argumenterror

Comment: I did it a bit different, I let the routes be unnamed and implemented `root_path` in my `ApplicationHelper` to point to `'/'`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if route api provides that, but I would do this tricks.Here you can render different different views based on dynamic values as followings.

```
def for_a_condition_action
    # render your view here
end

def for_b_condition_action
    # render your view here
end

def home
    if condition_a
      render :for_a_condition_action && return 
    elsif condition_b
      render :for_b_condition_action && return
    elsif more_condition...
    end 
end
```